# PGF/TikZ Clipping & Drawing: How to customize lines?

Tags: tikz-pgf, color, path-clipping

I have gotten some undesirable behavior with PGF/TikZ related to clipping and drawing paths with different color, say gray. So I tried with no success to exchange between `\clip[draw=gray]`, `\draw[clip,gray]` or `\path[draw=gray, clip]` or maybe using indirectly styles, the Emacs' output throws a TeX error message:

```
Extra options not allowed for clipping path command...
```

the only way to do so is by using scopes:

```
\begin{scope}[draw=gray] ... \end{scope}
```

Unfortunately, this technique requires that all the scoped objects' lines should be switched to black. So is there a trickery way to achieve this without passing by scope environment?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `clip` command in tikz is not made to actually draw a path, it is meant to delimit to region. That is why the drawing option don't work with it. The error message

```
Extra options not allowed for clipping path command...
```

you were getting is saying exactly that.

However, if you still want to draw along the clipping path, it is possible, by using a `preaction` or a `postaction`.

When a path command contains the `preaction` option it takes the same path and does things before the main path is created. For example, if you use the command

```
\path[clip,preaction = {draw=red,ultra thick}] (0,0) circle[radius=1];
```

will use the circle to clip any of the following commands, but before that it will draw the circle with a red and ultra thick line.

Answer (score 5):

From a user's point of view, the difficulty with simultaneously clipping and drawing a path is that these two operations are not commutative, and there is no obvious order to apply.  Contrast this with drawing and filling: again, the two operations are not commutative but it is fairly clear that one should fill and then draw.

So the program doesn't allow draw-with-clip, at least so long as the command to draw-and-clip is explicit enough for it to detect it.  Rather, you have to use a solution such as Frederic's where you must explicitly declare whether you want to draw first and clip after or the other way around (by either interchanging the `clip` and `draw` or by using a `postaction` instead of a `preaction`).

Incidentally, drawing along the same path as the clip is a neat solution to the problem of drawing on one side of a line.  I've used that somewhere here ...

Here's a bit of code to help illustrate the above:

```
\documentclass{article}
%\url{http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/42714/86}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line width=3mm]
\begin{scope}
\path[clip, preaction={draw}] (0,0) circle[radius=2cm];
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}
\path[clip, postaction={draw}] (5,0) circle[radius=2cm];
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: clipped and drawn paths (revised version)]